# Escape quotes on string javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, quotes

I have a variable with this kind of string: 4.5"x8.5"x0.5"

I found many answers about how to escape the quotes, so I write this function:

```
function replaceQuotesChars (str)
{
    var s = str.trim();

    // s.replace('"','&quot;');

    // s.replace('"','\\"');

    // s.replace(/\"/g,'\\"');

    s.replace(/\"/g,'&quot;');

    return s;
};
```

But none of those help me to escape the quotes because I get the same string that I submit to the function.

I save that variable with a stringify object to the database so when I parse back the string I get an error.

What I'm doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: string variables are immutable, you'll need to store the result of the `replace` function. Something like `s = s.replace(....)`.

Comment: ```s = s.replace(/"/g,"");```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a `.replace` (or really just about any other string manipulation method) a new string is returned because strings are ["immutable" objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) (can't be modified once created). Your code assumes the operation happens "in-place". You need to capture the new string (which incidentally, you did do with the `.trim()` operation).

In the following code:

1. First `.trim()` is called on `str`, which copies the string in `str` but without the leading and trailing spaces, and then returns that new string.
2. On that new string, `.replace()` is called, which copies the trimmed string, but with the characters replaced and then returns a new string.
3. That final string is what is then returned by the function.

```js
function replaceQuotesChars (str, delimeter) {
  // Each string operation returns a new string. Take that final
  // string and return it
  return str.trim().replace(/\"/g, delimeter);
};

console.log(replaceQuotesChars('10.5" x 4.75"', "&quot;"));
console.log(replaceQuotesChars('10.5" x 4.75"', "\'"));
console.log(replaceQuotesChars('10.5" x 4.75"', "\""));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Scott Marcus has already answered the question but if you are confused using regex(like me) there is an alternate method using the .split() method.

```
var a = str.split("\"");
var newS=""
for(var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
    if(a[1]!= ""){
        newS = newS + a[i];
    }
}
return newS;
```

This runs slower than regex but does the job.

Comment: The OP was already using the same RegEx in his original code, so one would assume he understood what it does.

Comment: regex101.com would be a great resource to understand Regex @Vignesh Sriram